# can we open gz file with Tcl_FSOpenFileChannel

Tags: tcl

Can we open gz file with Tcl_FSOpenFileChannel api https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcl_fsopenfilechannel

Comment: In C, look into http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/TclZlib.htm (but it's easier to just work with gzip files in straight up tcl)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and see the compressed data within it.

Decompression is done by stacking on a decompressor, likely `gunzip` for GZ-format data. The API for attaching one to a Tcl channel is currently only a Tcl script-level API; using it requires registering the channel (`Tcl_RegisterChannel`) to let Tcl scripts in that interpreter see that channel, and then running [`zlib push gzip`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/zlib.htm) to do the registration.

```c
Tcl_Channel chan = Tcl_FSOpenFileChannel(interp, theFileNameObj, "rb", 0);
// Should check for error here (NULL == chan), of course

Tcl_RegisterChannel(interp, chan);

char buffer[128]; // plenty of space; channel names aren't *that* long
sprintf(buffer, "zlib push gunzip %s", Tcl_GetChannelName(chan));
Tcl_Eval(interp, buffer);
// Ought to check result of Tcl_Eval for TCL_ERROR

// Use the file here

Tcl_Close(NULL, chan);
```

You can use the [Tcl zlib support](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/TclZlib.htm) library functions to do decompression (there's both a bulk and a streaming API described on that page), but attaching to a channel isn't one of the options. (I've added [a ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/7d56d711e3fd75e47b49cdc8a16f5bdc7022d162) to remind someone to make this nicer.)